# Font size is changed in VS2010 editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor

Sometimes, when I work with C/C++ source files in VS2010 editor, window font size is changed. Usually, when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. To restore font size to original value, I close and open the window again. Is there faster way to do this, for example, some keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Not an answer, but could help you. I usually change the font size pressing CTRL and using the scroll wheel on my mouse

Comment: Just to add to Steve's suggestion: There's an extension that will apply the current scroll setting to all code windows. I find that really helpful when doing presentations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Holding down the control button and scrolling in or out is a quick way of changing the font size displayed.